# IPv6 regex issue

Tags: regex, bash, ipv6

So no this is not technically a duplicate post. I am trying to determine why I can not get my split up regex to validate. I decided to split it up so it's more readable. It worked at one point, but now for some reason, I cant seem to get it to cooperate. Did I accidentally add something where I should not have? The extra (|) at the very beginning of the regex is to allow an empty IPv6 address.

Here is the code: (Yes this is in a function, I just didn't include the rest.)

```
local IPV6="^(|([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,6}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,6}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}|"
"(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,7}|:):|"
":(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7}|"
"((([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6})(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|"
"(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}|"
"([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}|"
"(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}|:):(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}|"
":(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})$"

if [[ !( $ADDRESS =~ $IPV6 ) ]]; then 
  echo "OOPS"
  return
fi
```

Comment: What is the error? Or what case does your regex not work?

Comment: It doesn't work period. It's not doing anything.

Comment: You probably need the flag to ignore whitespace; it's likely taking the line breaks literally and including them in the expression.

Comment: This is an unbelievably bad idea, and a perfect example of using the wrong tool for the job. You should be using a language that has an `inet_pton()` function, and then possibly call into that from your shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the shorthand `\d` does not work in bash. The following works for me:

```
R10='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-f]{1,4}'
R11='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,6}'
R12='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}'
R13='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}'
R14='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}'
R15='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}'
R16='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,6}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}'
R17='(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,7}|:):'
R18=':(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7}'
R0='(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])){3}'
R1='(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6})'
R2='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}:'
R3='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}:'
R4='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}:'
R5='([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}:'
R6='(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}|:):'
R7=':(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}:'
local IPV6="^(${R10}|${R11}|${R12}|${R13}|${R14}|${R15}|${R16}|${R17}|${R18}|${R19}|${R1}${R0}|${R2}${R0}|${R3}${R0}|${R4}${R0}|${R5}${R0}|${R6}${R0}|${R7}${R0})\$"
if [[ !( $ADDRESS =~ $IPV6 ) ]]; then 
  echo "OOPS"
  return
fi
```